# define a cclayer in .h file

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cclayer

In my I've defined a CCLayer like this:

```
@interface MyLayer : CCLayer {
    CCLayer * referenceLayer; 
}
```

How should I declare it to use it in +(CCScene *) scene ?

Like this ?

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCLayer *referenceLayer;
```

Comment: Prefer to rewrite the code so that you can do it in the -(id) init method.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: I'm sorry but I didn't get what you mean; What I'm trying to achieve is to get some sprites from another layer... Do you know any possibility rather than `CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *)[referenceLayer getChildByTag:kTagNumber];` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since  `+ (id)scene` is a class method, you cannot access an ivar/property from within it. One possible solution is having a static variable in your layer.m file, like in the following snippet:

```
static CCScene* _scene = nil;

+ (id)scene {
   if (_scene == nil) {
      _scene = [[CCScene node] retain];
      //-- further scene initializaion
   }
   return _scene;
 }
```

This simple approach has a drawback: you can only have one such layer around.

Comment: what about [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076699/accessing-an-object-from-class-type-method-in-iphone-cocos2d)?

Comment: it would also work, you only need to define: `+(id)scene:(CCLayer*)l` instead of `+ (id)scene`. In this case you will need to `alloc-init` the layer in advance and `scene` cannot act as a factory method.

Comment: Can you update your answer? Actually I'm trying to add the `bLayer` as child to the `referenceLayer`; do you think that's possible?